# Setting up RSS feed (Google shopping) for Vue-storefront based webshop

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, rss, vue-storefront

I have set up a Vue-storefront based webshop where I want to advertise on Google Shopping. I want to use an RSS feed for products and not sure how to properly set it up as I am getting `"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"` when running `"yarn feed"` in the root folder.

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

- 1. Go to project folder; cd vue-storefront
- 2. create "scripts" folder; `mkdir scripts`
- 3. Go to scripts folder; `cd scripts` and use the code [in this repository](https://github.com/Decntdefalt/feed.js/blob/master/feed.js) to make a new file; `touch feed.json`
- 4. add jsontoxml repository in `vue-storefront/node_modules`, get it [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iJNLRA9lz3a3A_UaheUPFWtoZICBcbrM?usp=sharing)
- 5. Edit package.json in projectfolder/vue-storefront and add 
  "feed": "node scripts/feed.js", under `"scripts"` section `"scripts"`: {
- 6. `yarn feed`

**Expected result:**

```
The file was saved!
Done in 0.41s.
```

**Actual result:**

```
$ sudo yarn feed
yarn run v1.12.3
$ node scripts/feed.js
(node:2527) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at     
https://hoversport.no/api/catalog/hoversport.no/product/_search?size=9000&from=0&sort=&_source_exclude=configurable_children%2Cconfigurable_options%2Csgn&_source_include=type_id%2Csku%2Cproduct_links%2Ctax_class_id%2Cspecial_price%2Cspecial_to_date%2Cspecial_from_date%2Cname%2Cprice%2CpriceInclTax%2CoriginalPriceInclTax%2CoriginalPrice%2CspecialPriceInclTax%2Cid%2Cimage%2Csale%2Cnew%2Curl_key%2Cstatus%2Ctier_prices%2Cdescription 
reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at /opt/bitnami/apps/hoversport.no/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/body.js:48:31
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:2527) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2527) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Done in 0.35s.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like vue-storefront-api is not responding or responding with an error

```
https://hoversport.no/api/catalog/hoversport.no/product/_search?size=9000&from=0&sort=&_source_exclude=configurable_children%2Cconfigurable_options%2Csgn&_source_include=type_id%2Csku%2Cproduct_links%2Ctax_class_id%2Cspecial_price%2Cspecial_to_date%2Cspecial_from_date%2Cname%2Cprice%2CpriceInclTax%2CoriginalPriceInclTax%2CoriginalPrice%2CspecialPriceInclTax%2Cid%2Cimage%2Csale%2Cnew%2Curl_key%2Cstatus%2Ctier_prices%2Cdescription 
reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I've got this error: 
[image]

It seems like there is no Elastic Search indexed named `hoversport.no` (probably its: `vue_storefront_catalog` ?)